# No room on ep ring?

Tags: linux, logs, usb, tty

I just switched to tty1, and I'm getting all kinds of output. It all looks like this:

```
[timestamp] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
```

It's happening over 100 times per second, every 5 seconds or so, on every tty. Other similar questions say it's happening because of external drives, but the only drive I have mounted is /dev/sda1 (root), as well as a swap partition on /dev/sda5

EDIT: Here's `mount` as root:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1008641,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=808160k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/eb5e28f7-395f-4556-aff4-8c8910a6295c on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=4924640k)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/lucas/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
truecrypt on /tmp/.truecrypt_aux_mnt1 type fuse.truecrypt (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/dev/mapper/truecrypt1 on /media/truecrypt1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

(Note that this issue started before the truecrypt volume was mounted)

My `dmseg` has been completely bloated out, nothing but this message.

After rebooting, my dmesg is back to normal. It's *way* too long to post here, so here's a pastebin link:

[dmesg](http://pastebin.com/p8yrcNPQ)

Comment: What do you mean those are the only drives mounted? You must have a `/` mounted somewhere and probably a `/home` as well.

Comment: @terdon that's what I'm saying. `/dev/sda1` at `/`, and that's it except for swap

Comment: Is this a USB 3.0 device?

Comment: Ah, OK, you meant _root_, your question said _boot_ hence my comment. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want my tty

The messages are most likely trying to tell you something. If you're only trying to use the `tty1` terminal without all messaging you can temporarily turn it down:

```
$ dmesg -n #
```

Where the `#` is a number such as 1,2,3,...

*excerpt from `dmesg` man page*

```
-n level
          Set the level at which logging of messages is done to the 
          console.  For example, -n 1 prevents all messages, except
          panic messages, from appearing on the console.  All levels of 
          messages are still written to /proc/kmsg, so syslogd(8) can 
          still be used to control exactly where kernel messages appear.
          When the -n option is used, dmesg will not print or clear the
          kernel ring buffer.
```

#### Debugging the message

If you're attempting to determine what the source of the messages is then we'lll need more information such as the output form the `mount` command and also look in the output of the `dmesg` command for this identical message and provide any lines before and after that seem relevant.

#### Known issue with USB 3.0 devices?

I found this thread over on Ask Ubuntu titled: [ERROR no room on ep ring with USB 3.0 device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187644/error-no-room-on-ep-ring-with-usb-3-0-device) which sounds like you're issue. Looks to already have a bug opened titled, ["ERROR no room on ep ring" fills up syslog and hard disk in minutes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/883646), but doesn't appear to have been resolved or even assigned at this point.

Comment: Updated with `mount` output.

Comment: @tkbx - is this a USB 3.0 device?

Comment: @tkbx - even after a reboot the `dmesg` is full already?

Comment: no, just SATA (sda1)

Comment: I rebooted and it seems to have stopped, but it would be nice to find out what caused this. Adding dmesg to question.

Comment: @tkbx - anything that you can recall which lead to this? What were you doing when started to notice this?

Comment: Can't really remember anything... I formatted a new USB drive to ext4 yesterday. It's USB 2, but I used my USB 3 port because the others were taken.