# ERROR: No room on ep ring

Tags: debian, usb

I built a pc around a Debian amd64 today. Every time I log in, I see hundreds of lines (that increase as the session proceeds) of ERROR: No room on ep ring.
I've seen another question of this type asked on this forum:

[No room on ep ring?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89073/no-room-on-ep-ring)
but that error seemed to have sorted out when the user rebooted. However, this stops only when I disable xhci mode from the bios.
Important points to note:
1. USB3 seems to work when enabled from the bios (as per hdparm) albeit not at desirable speeds (proof of which is in 2)
2. The syslog shows that the device is repeatedly disconnecting and connecting from the USB port.

```
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.205710] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.222393] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=a013
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.222402] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.222407] usb 3-2: Product: Backup+ BK
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.222411] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.222415] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: NA533VHH
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.291467] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.291524] scsi5 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.291569] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.291570] USB Mass Storage support registered.
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.705536] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.945509] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.962192] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=a013
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.962201] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.962206] usb 3-2: Product: Backup+ BK
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.962210] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.962214] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: NA533VHH
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc kernel: [  116.963037] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Dec 12 22:58:08 bassypc mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
. /*ERROR: No room on ep ring keeps filling up more lines here*/
.
.
Dec 12 22:58:09 bassypc kernel: [  117.961789] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Backup+ BK       0410 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Dec 12 22:58:09 bassypc kernel: [  117.965025] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Dec 12 22:58:12 bassypc kernel: [  117.965887] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk.....
.
.
.
Dec 12 22:58:12 bassypc kernel: [  120.976350] .ready
Dec 12 22:58:12 bassypc kernel: [  120.976735] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
Dec 12 22:58:13 bassypc kernel: [  121.159686] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Dec 12 22:58:13 bassypc kernel: [  121.159695] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
Dec 12 22:58:13 bassypc kernel: [  121.160046] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 12 22:58:13 bassypc kernel: [  121.170227]  sdb: sdb1
Dec 12 22:58:13 bassypc kernel: [  121.172725] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
.
.
.
Dec 12 22:58:24 bassypc kernel: [  132.601304] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

Any suggestions or advice to be able to use the USB3 port "normally"?

Comment: Can you edit your post?  If I do it you won't get a badge :)

Comment: What is your kernel version?

Comment: kernel version: Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2

Comment: Try upgrading to a kernel >= 3.4 and tell me if this goes away.  See [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187644/error-no-room-on-ep-ring-with-usb-3-0-device), and [this closed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/883646)

Comment: Ah yes, I've seen this post too. Pardon me for the noob-ish question but, I have to enable the jessie repository for this right?

Comment: Nope, [these instructions](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-the-linux-kernel-3-4-52-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-debian-derivates/) should work if you create a new directory and `cd` to it 1st

Comment: Problem solved! Installed kernel 3.16. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice work around for staying in your distro!  I said >=3.4, but you went < 3.2.  Since Wheezy is Stable LTS, this would qualify as a regression bug.  You should file one :)

Comment: A random google search tells me that Linux 3.16 was released in September 2014 whereas Linux 3.2 was released sometime in 2012, so I went > 3.2. :)

Comment: These version numbers always get me because I forget that 3.2 is not 3.20, so 3.16 > 3.2